Pass a Variable from Webpack to PHP
Is it possible to pass a variable from webpack to PHP? I tried using webpack.DefinePlugin but not sure if its possible to access the VAR in PHP. I am working in WordPress but dont think it matters. I will want to pass a variable that checks if Webpack is in Development mode or Productions mode in the future if its actually possible to pass a variable to PHP. This is what I tried.
webpack.config.js
const testingavar = 'My Value'; 
console.log(testingavar);

module.exports = {


    entry: {
      main: ['./src/index.js'],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),

      publicPath: webpackConfig.PUBLIC_PATH,
      filename: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'TESTING_A_VAR' : JSON.stringify('testingavar'), // var
      })
    ],
  };

PHP file
$testavar = defined('TESTING_A_VAR') ? TESTING_A_VAR : '';
var_dump($testavar); // This should output 'My Value'


In common with every other bit of JavaScript code which runs in a browser, if you want to pass a value from the JavaScript to a server-side script such as PHP, you'll need to send that variable's value to the server in a HTTP request. JS and PHP run in separate environments, usually on completely separate computers. They have no knowledge of other. Expecting a variable you defined in one language and environment to show up automatically in a completely different, separate environment makes no sense. You need to actually cause some communication between the two - in this case by using HTTP

As you hopefully know, there are multiple ways a browser can trigger a HTTP request and send data to the server - e.g. if a link is clicked on, or a form is submitted, or some JavaScript code generates a request (e.g by auto-submitting a form, or causing navigation via location.href, or by making an AJAX/fetch request). You can use whichever of these options makes sense in your particular scenario.

But I'm not familiar with webpack, so maybe this particular code runs on the command-line rather than in a browser? I wasn't sure. Either way, JS and PHP still don't automatically know about each other's variables! You'd have to put the value somewhere that PHP can read and use it when a PHP script executes - e.g. in a file or a database, something like that. I don't really know why your server-side code needs to know if your bundling system is in dev or prod mode though, it shouldn't need to concern itself with that kind of thing. What's the reason for this particular requirement?

Thanks. I will store my variable in a JSON file and then read it with PHP.

@hubvill, It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to generate a piece of PHP code to define a PHP variable/constant with the value passed from WebPack?

@RuslanOsmanov Basically I want to know when Webpack is running in Development or Productions mode in PHP. I was able to do this by creating a JSON file that contains my variables when webpack runs. And then I was able to read the JSON file in PHP.
